# Why does my if statement does not start my activity?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-intent, android-activity

I've been working this Android project.
Currently, I've been trying to make the app start an activity on login. 
I tried starting the activity before my if statement and also tried to log in the debugger what response is and succesfully got "Login success", so I do not know why that is happening.

```
private void loginUser(String email, String password) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email cannot be null or empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password cannot be null or empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    compositeDisposable.add(iMyService.loginUser(email, password)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String response) throws Exception {
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (response.equals("Login success")) {
                        // Log.d("myTag", "Login Success");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            })
    );


}
```

Comment: Then `response` does not equal the string `Login success`.

Comment: Can you check what response you are getting by doing `Log.d(response)` before if statement? Just to make sure what response is coming and what you are expecting.

Comment: I get Login success from Log.d("myTag", response);